# ffmpeg 4.0 decoded h264 slower than old version one(n2.8.14)

Tags: ffmpeg

I use ffmpeg to decode h264 and transcode to jpeg.
I used to use the 2.8 version, now change to 4.0.
The new version avcodec_decode_video2 is deprecated, so i use the new API (send, receive).
I found that the new version ffmpeg is much slower than the old one when decoding h264.
why is that? How to reach the original speed?

Here's the decoder init codes：
**version 2.8**

```
//2.8
if (avformat_open_input(&format_, path, NULL, &options) != 0) {
    printf("FileMediaBase: open input failed\n");
    return -1;
}
if (avformat_find_stream_info(format_, NULL) < 0) {
    printf("FileMediaBase: avformat_find_stream_info failed\n");
    avformat_close_input(&format_);
    return -1;
}
AVCodecContext *code_ctx = 0;
AVCodec *codec = 0;
// Find the first audio and video stream
for (int i = 0; i < format_->nb_streams; i++) {
    code_ctx = format_->streams[i]->codec;
    codec = avcodec_find_decoder(code_ctx->codec_id);
    if (code_ctx->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
        vcode_ctx_ = code_ctx;
        vstream_ = format_->streams[i];
    }else if (code_ctx->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO) {
        acode_ctx_ = code_ctx;
        astream_ = format_->streams[i];
    }
    // Open the codec
    if (!codec || (avcodec_open2(code_ctx, codec, NULL) < 0)) {
        printf("avcodec_open2() failed\n");
        avformat_close_input(&format_);
        return -1;
    }
```

**version 4.0**

```
if (avformat_open_input(&format_, path, NULL, &options) != 0) {
    printf("FileMediaBase: open input failed\n");
    return -1;
}
if (avformat_find_stream_info(format_, NULL) < 0) {
    printf("FileMediaBase: avformat_find_stream_info failed\n");
    avformat_close_input(&format_);
    return -1;
}
AVStream *st;
AVCodec *dec = NULL;
AVDictionary *opts = NULL;

ret = av_find_best_stream(format_, AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO, -1, -1, NULL, 0);
if (ret < 0) {
    return ret;
}
else {
    stream_index = ret;
    st = format_->streams[stream_index];

    /* find decoder for the stream */
    dec = avcodec_find_decoder(st->codecpar->codec_id);
    if (!dec) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to find %s codec\n",
            av_get_media_type_string(type));
        return AVERROR(EINVAL);
    }

    /* Allocate a codec context for the decoder */
    *dec_ctx = avcodec_alloc_context3(dec);
    if (!*dec_ctx) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate the %s codec context\n",
            av_get_media_type_string(type));
        return AVERROR(ENOMEM);
    }

    /* Copy codec parameters from input stream to output codec context */
    if ((ret = avcodec_parameters_to_context(*dec_ctx, st->codecpar)) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to copy %s codec parameters to decoder context\n",
            av_get_media_type_string(type));
        avcodec_free_context(dec_ctx);
        return ret;
    }

    /*if (dec->id == AV_CODEC_ID_H264) {
        (*dec_ctx)->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_TRUNCATED;
    }*/

    /* Init the decoders, with or without reference counting */
    //av_dict_set(&opts, "refcounted_frames", refcount ? "1" : "0", 0);
    if ((ret = avcodec_open2(*dec_ctx, dec, &opts)) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open %s codec\n",
            av_get_media_type_string(type));
        avcodec_free_context(dec_ctx);
        return ret;
    }
```

I print out the time spent on some API
[image]

Comment: Try the libav ML - http://ffmpeg.org/mailman/listinfo/libav-user

Comment: Now the project is not maintained by me alone, others are using the same shared libraries, unless others agree to replace with libav.

Comment: The libav-user mailing list is for user questions involving the FFmpeg libav* libraries. It doesn't have anything to do with the Libav fork (who did a disservice to users by choosing a name already being used by FFmpeg).

Answer (score 6):

I've solved this problem, change the number of decoding threads(default is 1 in version 4.0) to 6(default is 6 in version 2.8).

```
(*dec_ctx)->thread_count = 6;
```

Comment: This is so stupid. I was running around with a newer version of FFMPEG not knowing why avcodec_send_packet took forever to run compared to the older version of FFMPEG all because the default thread count is 1. Thank you for you answer.

Answer (score 5):

I have faced the same issue when decoding h264 video stream using ffmpeg 2.8.14 and 4.0.1 versions. 
In both cases when accessing the codec context after avformat_find_stream_info()

```
AVFormatContext *pFormatCtx;
AVCodecContext* pCodecCtxOrig;
...
avformat_find_stream_info(pFormatCtx, NULL)
...
for (uint i = 0; i < pFormatCtx->nb_streams; i++)
{
  if (pFormatCtx->streams[i]->codec->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO)
  {
    pCodecCtxOrig = pFormatCtx->streams[i]->codec;
    ...

  }
}
```

then the pCodecCtxOrig::thread_count is actually set to 0, which means that ffmpeg library finds suitable thread_count by itself based on CPU cores when opening codec context with `avcodec_open2()`. In my case the thread count was set to 5.

In case of 2.8.14 the pCodecCtxOrig::thread_count is set to 0 and when doing a copy from it

```
AVCodecContext* pCodecCtxOrig;
AVCodecContext* pCodecCtx;
....
avcodec_copy_context(pCodecCtx, pCodecCtxOrig)
```

the thread_count is copied as well.

In case of 4.0.1 the `avcodec_copy_context()` is deprecated and the `avcodec_parameters_to_context()` should be used instead. The coping struct `AVCodecParameters` is not containing thread_count thus the info gets lost. Thread count remains the default value 1, which is set by `avcodec_alloc_context3`. To overcome the problem set `thread_count` to 0 before opening the codec context.

Comment: This is really helpful, setting thread_count=0 does the trick.